# Renaming arrays of varying sizes

Tags: arrays, r, mongodb

In `Step 1`, I find what type of data exists in Database.
In `step 2`, I retrieve all data from Database and try to store into arrays of varying sizes

**1**. Accessing data from MongoDB

```
    mong <- mongo(collection = "mycollection", db = "dbname", url = "mongodb://localhost")

    agg_df <- mong$aggregate('[{ "$group" : 
                          { "_id" : "$tagname", 
                            "number_records" : { "$sum" : 1}
                          }
                      }]')

    print(agg_df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
                _id         number_records
      1         raees            100
      2   DearZindagi            100
      3           FAN            100
      4           DDD             21
```

**NOTE**: `Step 1 output` indicates that there are 4 types of categories with records of 100,100,100,21 each.

**2**. From STEP 1, I need to create `4 arrays` consisting of `1 column` and varying nos. of `rows(100,100,100,21)` and give `names` to those array as `Raees,DearZindagi,FAN,DDD`

```
     Dataset <- mong$find('{}','{"text":1}')  
     Dataset$text <- sapply(Dataset$text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))  
     typeof(Dataset$text)  
     > [1] "character"
```

**3**. The arrays and their sizes(in rows) to be created is `dependent` on output of Step 1. There would never be a case where the output of `step 1` would be more than 15 rows.

How should i do this?.

4. The split function would splits the Dataset into arrays, how shall i rename these arrays:

   ```
   rows <- nrow(agg_df)
   for (i in 1:rows){
   array<- split(Dataset$text, rep(1:rows, c(agg_df[i,2])))
   }
   ```

Comment: Given you have successfully created `agg_df`, it would appear everything before this (i.e., Steps 1 & 2) is irrelevant?

Comment: Step 1 indicates how much arrays should be created and their sizes, Step 2 provides me with Dataset(421 rows). The content of Dataset is inserted into the arrays that are splitted i.e(array[1:1] consists first 100 records, array[2:2] consists next 100 records and so on...)    I want to specify seperate names like  `raees` name for array[1:1], `DearZindagi` for array[2:2] and so on...

Comment: You should make your question reproducible by providing the output of `dput(head(agg_df))` and `dput(head(Dataset))` (or a subset of each that makes the question meaningful).